# How to convert Object of Arrays to Objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

I have some data coming from the MVC controller in the below format:

`{id: Array[3], city: Array[3]}`

I wanted to convert that data into

`[Object, Object, Object]`

which will have the structure `Object0{id, city}`, `Object1{id, city}`, `Object2{id, city}`

I tried the below method but didnt work out

```
angular.forEach(data, function(){

    vm.Cities = {
        id :data.citiesIDs,
        city : data.citiesStr
    }

});
```

Can anyone please give me a hint as in where i am going wrong or what is the best way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You stated that you want the output but be an array with 3 objects, but your initial object looks like it only has _two_ items in each of the arrays, where is the third object coming from?

Comment: You are assigning the new object to vm.Cities every iteration. If vm.Cities is an array, you should .push the new object onto it.

Comment: can you give me a clearer idea of what the controller gives you - it is an array of objects OR 1 object, with a city, id - keys, and do you want to unwind the arrays and hand back objects based on them.. see what I am saying?

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad. Corrected the post now

Comment: it returns just one object with city, id keys and i want an object to have only one id and city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need Angular for this, plain Javascript works just as well.

```
function transform(object) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < object.id.length; i++) {
    result.push({
      id: object.id[i],
      city: object.city[i]
    });
  }
  return result;
}
```

Then you can call your helper with your data:

```
var list = transform(data); // <-- list of (id,city) objects
```

Keep in mind the function assumes both of your `id` and `city` arrays are of the same length (which really wouldn't make sense if they weren't), BUT for the case they're not of the same length, you would want to make a minor change in your for loop:

```
var maxLen = Math.max(object.id.length, object.city.length);
for (var i = 0; i < maxLen; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple JS operation and [here is the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wctazg75/)

```
// Assuming obj is defined and both obj.id and obj.city are arrays

var obj = {
    id: [25, 82, 188, 141],
    city: ['Tokyo', 'Munich', 'Los Angeles', 'Sao Paolo'],
};

var max = Math.max(obj.id.length, obj.city.length);

var results = [];

for(var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    var converted = {
        id: obj.id[i] ? obj.id[i] : null,
        city: obj.city[i] ? obj.city[i] : null
    };
    results.push(converted);
}

console.log('Coverted array', results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple example. Iterate over one of the arrays and grab from the other by index.

```
var cities = []
angular.forEach(data.id, function(id, index) {
    var city = {id: id, city: data.city[index]};
    cities.push(city);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterator can help you. e.g.:

```
var data = {id: [1,2], city: ['Curitiba','São Paulo']};
    var array = [];
    for(var prop in data){
        var length = data[prop].length;
        for(var z = 0; z < length; z++){
            if(!array.hasOwnProperty(z)){
                array[z] = {};
            }
            array[z][prop] = data[prop][z];
        }
    }
    console.log(array);// [Object{city:'Curitiba',id:1},Object{city:'São Paulo',id:2}]
```